# Is there an online site to play Titan Boardgame

Tags: online, titan

I know of [ACTS](http://acts.warhorsesim.com/ttn.asp) and it works quite well. But in times of Web 2.0 I wonder -- is there an alternative to play Titan against friends (and mybe foes)?

Answer (score 3):

There's not a site I know of, but there is Java-based software:

http://colossus.sourceforge.net/

Comment: That is an excellent program, yes. But that one allows you to play synchronous-only, not asynchronously. For a real 3-6 player game not suited. 2... ok, but even that, not so good. A Client-Server solution with log-on mechanism would be preferable.

Comment: I think you're out of luck, then. I've played Titan a lot, using a variety of different tools, and I'm not aware of anything that's a better fit for your requirements than ACTS.

Comment: Only tinkered with this one, but it looks pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

There's the [Titan HD app](http://dauba-dauba.net/titan.html) from [Dauba-Dauba Enterprises](http://dauba-dauba.net/index.html). On the amazon website it says that it features "Online multi-player".